# Spring Integration Twitter - get latest tweets

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

How can I specify to a `search-inbound-channel-adapter` to poll only for the latest tweets. By latest tweets I mean tweets within x minutes/hours/days or from the last tweet polled.

I want to avoid receiving duplicate tweets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inbound Twitter adapters do keep track of the latest ID, so you should not see duplicates while it's running. However, the default implementation of the MetadataStore (the component responsible for tracking that) stores the metadata in memory only. Therefore, it's possible to receive duplicates after a restart. As of version 3.0, you can provide a "metadata-store" reference when configuring the adapter, and we now provide a RedisMetadataStore out of the box. Configuring an instance of that and referencing it from the adapter will ensure that the information about last tweet seen is stored in redis rather than a Map in-process.

For more info, see:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/twitter.html#twitter-inbound

Hope that helps.

-Mark

Answer (score 1):

You won't get duplicates because the adapter keeps track of the id of the last tweet sent to the channel.

This information is stored in a `MetadataStore` by default, it's an in-memory store so won't survive a system restart.

You can configure a persistent metadata store - a simple file store (properties file) or, in 3.0 a `Redis` store is available.

See [the documentation for more information](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/twitter.html#twitter-inbound)

If you want to use more advanced search techniques, you can use the Twitter [rest api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) with an http outbound gateway.